# Objects whose limiting behaviour resembles a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, limits

Is there a name for a structure that isn't a group, but that begins to behave like a group the more operations are performed? I'm trying to take the idea of an attractor from dynamical systems and impose some algebraic structure on the limiting set. Here's a tentative definition.

Consider a set $S$ with a proper subset $G$ and a binary operation $\circ: S \times S\rightarrow S$, such that:

$–$ $(G,\circ)$ forms a group

$–$ $S$ is closed under $\circ$

$–$ if $a \in G$ or $b \in G$, then  $a\circ b \in G$

In addition, define a function $\|\cdot\|:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies:

$–$ $\|g\|=0, \forall g \in G$

$–$ $\|a\|>0, \forall a \in S\backslash G$

$–$ $\|a\circ b\|< \|a\|$, and $\|a\circ b\|< \|b\|, \forall a,b \in S\backslash G$

The function $\|\cdot\|$ is meant to be a measure of distance from $G$.

Here's an example.

Consider $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{0\}$, with coordinates expressed in polar form. Define $\|(r,\theta)\|=|r-1|$, and $(r_1,\theta_1)\circ(r_2,\theta_2)=(1+\frac{r_\min}{2},\theta_1+\theta_2)$, where $r_\min=\min(\|(r_1,\theta_1)\|,\|(r_2,\theta_2)\|)$. The group in this case is the set where $r=1$.

Does this kind of object (or something that behaves like it) exist in any field of study?